# Pulling all venues corresponding to specific place

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

In my `wp_posts` table in WordPress i have `post_type = 'venue'` .I'am trying to fetch all venues for United States with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'venue' and `post_title` = 'United States'
```

but i got 0 matches. And it's 100% sure that i have existing venues. Any ideas ?
The country United States is in other post_type called 'place'

Comment: please post some sample data

Comment: What do you mean by "sample data " ?

Comment: On which you expect the results and not getting any.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a separate `post_type` for places and that the `United States` is one of the places, then your queries does nothing.

What your query is doing is Searching for `venue` `post_type` that have `United States` as `post_title`.

if `places` are going to be attributes of the `venues`, then you need to set them as `post_meta`.